# How can I find all the distinct pair of values in a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database table, which has a primary key `id` and two fields `installation_id` and `stat_value`.

An installation_id can have more than one stat_value and same is applicable for stat_value. I want to find all the records, i.e. all the installation_ids associated with stat_values.

Answer (score 7):

This might be what you are after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT installation_id, stat_value FROM your_table;
```